# How I can manage ManipulationDelta on maps-like application?

Tags: windows-phone-7, maps, gestures

I'm trying to create maps application like the WP7 Maps. I know that in WPF it's simple to manage map canvases gestures through MatrixTransform, but WP7's version of MatrixTransform is less functional. 
**Is there any patterns** how to manage all ManipulationDelta events to:

- Zoom in and zoom out. Now I make it like that:

  ```
  var maxScale = Math.Max(
      args.DeltaManipulation.Scale.X,
      args.DeltaManipulation.Scale.Y);

  if (Math.Abs(maxScale - 0) > 0.0001 &&
      ((maxScale < 1 && _scale.ScaleX > MIN_SCALE) ||
       (maxScale > 1 && _scale.ScaleX < MAX_SCALE)))
  {
      _scale.ScaleX *= maxScale;
      _scale.ScaleY *= maxScale;
  }
  ```

where _scale = new ScaleTransform(); and it has to be improved to manage position of canvas

- Move map by finger. By first step it's look like:

  ```
  _translation.X += args.DeltaManipulation.Translation.X
      * _scale.ScaleX;

  _translation.Y += args.DeltaManipulation.Translation.Y
      * _scale.ScaleX;
  ```

where _translation = new TranslateTransform();

- Make some dynamic after Pan, Pinch and Stretch

no current implementation, but I'm looking at ManipulationCompleted, where add some code to "continue" gestures in more natural way.

I'm looking for typical solution to manage this features, may be my way is wrong and not through ManipulationDelta

Comment: Why not just use the MapControl which comes with the framework?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After a little research I've decided to use this behaviour to add multitouch http://gallery.expression.microsoft.com/MultiTouch/

If something goes wrong I can just see at reflected code and create something like that